# Auth::check() for client credential workflow with Passport

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I have a Laravel app where some routes are protected with the `'client'` middleware from Laravel Passport (Example from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passport#client-credentials-grant-tokens)):

```
Route::get('/orders', function (Request $request) {
  ...
})->middleware('client');
```

When I need to explicitly check for the success of authentication in my code, I normally do this with:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth::check();
```

However, this function appears to always return `false` with the client credentials workflow. I understand that e.g. `Auth::user()` does not make sense in this context but `Auth::check()` should be well-defined in this situation.

**Question:** Is there an alternative to `Auth::check()` for the client credentials workflow or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the Access Token in header first, after doing so you should be able to check auth like this:

```
Auth::guard('api')->check()
```

Comment: This gives me `false` as well.